# Import Neo4j into TitanDB

Tags: groovy, neo4j, titan, tinkerpop3

I have tried to achieve this by using this [snippet](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#_loading_with_bulkloadervertexprogram) 
But `class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph` does not support graph computer.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: How large is your neo4j graph (i.e. number of edges)? There tend to be different strategies for different graph sizes.

Comment: 800K Vertices & 160 million Edges